# What is best in a website, use an image url or download the image?

Tags: image, web, caching, storage, supabase

I am trying to optimise my website so that I can spend less money on database, specifically images. I use Supabase as my DB and storage.

Right now I directly use the URL of the images in the storage, but I am not sure if it would be better to download the images and then display them, as they will be in the caché, while in the URL case they won't, right? (To be clear, there are two separate supabase functions for this, one for getting url and one for downloading).

I have noticed that, when using the URL, the first render is much slower and subsequent renders are way faster, but I am unable to find the images in my caché, that's why I was wondering which option was better.

Are there any best pratices on this topic?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to save space, you should use the URL because it saves space on storage, though downloading the image results in faster rendering.

1. Saving space -> Slower Rendering -> URL
2. Using more storage -> Faster Rendering -> Downloaded IMG